# To handle windows save dialog box in IE11

Tags: selenium, autoit

Can someone help me with the windows dialog box handling in selenium using auto IT.
I want to press save. Have used `Send('!s')` in AutoIt script and called in my program using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Selenium\\FileDownload.exe")`. 
This saves the doc but after that program errors out.
Have also used robot class but it did not work for me.

```
    Robot robot=new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to call your AutoIT script if the script runs perfectly fine when it is run independently.
`String strModalDialogExeName = "C:\\Selenium\\FileUpload.exe";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(strModalDialogExeName);            p.waitFor();

int intExitCode = p.exitValue();

System.out.println(intExitCode);
p.destroy();`